# Python multiprocessing's manager list has no lock?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, thread-safety

I use multiprocessing's manager to create a list to share between two process. They simply add 1 for 20 times. Finally, I found that the final result is not 40. It seems the manager's list is not process-safe?
The code are as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(l):
    for i in range(20):
        l[0] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list([0] * 10)
    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(l,))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=(l,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print (l)
```

The result is

```
[26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I share a list in a process-safe way?

Comment: Individual operations are atomic, but `l[0] += 1` is **two** operations on the managed list.

Comment: If you want a lock, make a lock.

Comment: Tell your Python version and try `l = manager.list(range(10))`